# Android: оффлайн режим приложения

Tags: activity, android, android-offline, java

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решается задача с выводом в оффлайне режиме отдельного лэйаута, например как у приложения ВК?

Я реализовал это так:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (isOnline()) {
            //основной код активити
        } else {
            offlineRun(NotificationsActivity.class); // Здесь я вывожу активити с сообщением что подключение отсутствует и кнопкой "подключиться заново", передаваемый в функцию параметр NotificationsActivity.class нужен для создания интента и запуска активити заново.
        }
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что этот if мне надо пихать в каждую создаваемую активити, хотелось бы решение на более общем уровне, есть какие-нибудь мысли на этот счет? Как кто решал эту задачу?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поместить этот код в базовую реализацию `Activity`, а остальных наследовать от неё.

Comment: А как я в базовой активити узнаю, какую активити мне надо передать в offlineRun? И как мне запустить основной код вызываемой активити?

Comment: @falstaf - накидал [код][1], что писать в те места где вопросы?

[1]: http://pastebin.com/VnNB7sEK

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что в `offlineRun` параметром передаётся класс текущей `activity`?

Comment: @falstaf - всё верно, что бы по нажатию кнопки происходила "перезагрузка" активити.
Код не претендует на уникальность, возможно есть другой способ "перезагрузить" активити, я был бы рад только узнать о существовании такого, это упростило бы задачу и уменьшило код

Comment: Ну так и вызывайте как `offlineRun(getClass())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так: http://pastebin.com/2CUvxAc0

Comment: @falstaf Спасибо!